# Ricci timeout issue

Tags: redhat, cluster

I'm just playing around with Conga and it looks very neat... if only it worked well enough!

It was working great when I was setting up the cluster. I could click around all over the Luci interface and no problems. Now that I'm actually running a cluster service (MySQL, FWIW), Luci frequently times out when I click on something (nodes, fence devices, etc).

It is definitely ricci playing up. I've started ricci up in debug/foreground mode and for successful requests it shows:

```
client added
ClientInstance.cpp:144: exception: SSL_read() error: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL: Success
request completed in 302 milliseconds
client removed
```

For ones that fail, it shows:

```
client added
ClientInstance.cpp:144: exception: Receive timeout
request completed in 120915 milliseconds
client removed
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After removing the cluster config and starting again, it seems to have "fixed" itself. As it is no longer reproducible, I am closing this question.

Comment: feel free to accept this answer. That closes it as far as ServerFault is concerned.